# Automatic changing of rows and columns for facet_wrap()

Tags: r

How would one automate the control of columns and rows in facet_wrap such that there will never be any empty spaces? For example, my facet_wrap() code displays 24 plots with 5 columns and rows, but would like to have 4 columns and 6 rows. I know one can control the output within facet_wrap, but would like a solution that can automate this when producing multiple ggplots.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit long-winded, but it should give you the most "balanced" pair of rows and columns for a given `n_plots` (`n_plots` being the number of distinct values in the variable you are using to facet on):

```r
n_plots <-  24

possible_arrangements <- data.frame()

ind = 1
for (i in 1:n_plots) {
  if (n_plots%%i == 0){
    j = n_plots/i
    print(paste(i,j)) #for debugging purposes
    possible_arrangements[ind,1] <- i
    possible_arrangements[ind,2] <- j
    ind = ind + 1
    }

}

colnames(possible_arrangements) <- c("rows", "cols")

possible_arrangements <- possible_arrangements %>% 
  mutate(balance = abs(rows-cols))

solution <- possible_arrangements %>% 
  filter(balance == min(balance))
```

Output:

```r
> solution
  rows cols balance
1    4    6       2
2    6    4       2
```

If you want an unique solution then you can further require that `cols>=rows` or `rows>=cols` depending on how you like it.